# How to show the same tab content for multiple tabs in jquery / javascript.

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example i have tabs like 1,2, 3, 4,5 now when user selected 2,3,4 tabs we need to show the same content and the remaining tabs different. How i can do this one .

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap accordion or collapse and for same content tabs set the same content id.

Comment: can u give me any Suggestion like example

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion
There are id="collapseOne" , id="collapseTwo", id="collapseThree" for contents and href="#collapseOne", href="#collapseTwo", href="#collapseThree" for tabs. If you want that the first and the second links open the first content you should change the href to href="#collapseOne" .

Comment: Thanks , but won't write the 3 div , i will write only one time , in that i have some drop down values

Comment: We will write the single div like ,<div id='tab2' or  id ='tab3' or id ='tab4'  > <p>Show data</p> </div>  we need to show that data. when ever user is click on any three those tabs .